# Configure disaster recovery and automatic failover for Azure Key vault?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, disaster-recovery

We have our Azure key vault provisioned in East US and our hot-stand by region is West US.

Does it support Geo-Replication?

How do I configure the Azure Key vault to support the disaster recovery with automatic failover? Would it impact the connection string?

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation, its provided by default

> "If individual components within the key vault service fail, alternate
> components within the region step in to serve your request to make
> sure that there is no degradation of functionality. You don't need to
> take any action to start this process, it happens automatically and
> will be transparent to you.
>
> In the rare event that an entire Azure region is unavailable, the
> requests that you make of Azure Key Vault in that region are
> automatically routed (failed over) to a secondary region except in the
> case of the Brazil South region. When the primary region is available
> again, requests are routed back (failed back) to the primary region.
> Again, you don't need to take any action because this happens
> automatically."

You can read the whole documentation here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/disaster-recovery-guidance